# JSON not displaying with angular ng-repeater

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any advice? Nothing is displaying on the page, but it shows fine in console. I feel like I should be using $scope somehow, but I can't get it to work. Thanks for any help in advance!

FILE.JSON

```
[{
 "firstName": "Foo",
 "lastName": "Johnson"
 }, {
 "firstName": "Bar",
 "lastName": "Simpson"
 }
]
```

CONTROLLER

```
app.controller('nameSearchController', function($http) {
  $http.get('file.json').success(function(data){
    searchResults = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(searchResults);
  })
});
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-controller="nameSearchController">
   <li ng-repeat="rows in searchResults">
       {{ rows.firstName }} {{ rows.lastName }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add $scope to your injections and then assign the data to $scope.searchResults

Comment: Thanks. I did this. There are no errors, but no data is displayed. Could it be something with ui.router & views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
angular.module("app",[])
  .controller('nameSearchController', function($http,$scope) {
      $http.get('json.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.searchResults = data;

  })
});
```

Here is a plunkr with the solution:

http://embed.plnkr.co/HwZORGULG44lbFWGyans/preview

Comment: Somehow having the code in front of me made a difference. I added the scope but it still wasn't working. When I pasted your code it started working. I think I was missing a semicolon or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('nameSearchController', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('file.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.searchResults = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log($scope.searchResults);
  })
});
```

Comment: I made this change, but the results still don't show. Should the directive look like this now?:
<li ng-repeat="rows in $scope.searchResults">

Comment: No, did you add ng-App and ng-Controller tags in your view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $scope and instead of JSON.stringify which transforms json to string you should use json.parse which does the oposite.

```
app.controller('nameSearchController', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('file.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.searchResults = JSON.parse(data);
  })
});
```